# Can a human wizard use Versatility to get an extra spell matrix?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

The **Versatility** talent allows a human character to learn a talent from Disciplines other than their own.

As part of the limitations of it it states: (p120 ED First Edition)

> Characters with Versatility cannot buy talents available in their own discipline.

However spell matrixes are available at multiple levels and it's an oddball in that you buy the same talent repeatedly for extra spells to store in them.

So can a human wizard use Versatility to get an extra (third) spell matrix at level one?

Comment: A cite with page and book would be useful, especially since there are about five (or so) different editions.

Comment: added in reference :)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, are you referring to FASA's original ED? :)

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no, human wizards can't buy an extra Spell Matrix with Versatility.

Sure, other magician Disciplines also have access to Spell Matrix, but the RAW do not state that there would be a separate version for all of them. Spell Matrix is the same for each and every magician Discipline -- unlike Thread Weaving, a talent whose buying the description of Versatility explicitly allows --, therefore it should be considered as available for a human magician within their own Discipline, which fact in turn forbids its buying with Versatility.

Comment: +1 for specifying the edition (smooth!) and for recalling that thread weaving is explicitly mentioned. :-) In that light I can delete my answer, as it should be reworded to "yes, but only since 2nd edition..." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can only buy talents you will not gain in your progression path. So a wizard can not use Versatility to gain a Talent at lower level that he will receive at a higher level. But then the golden rule has always been whatever works for your campaign :-)

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to the site. Please read the [FAQ} (http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) if you have any questions and enjoy! Also, if you have a page reference for the that rule, it would definitely help improve the answer.